# Using prepared statements in PHP with the IN function in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, tags

I'm working on a tagging system using 3 tables (normalised). I wanted to create a prepared statement for when some searches for example "red apples", that it brings up all the items which have been tagged "red" and "apples".

Currently my query looks something like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT co.content_id, co.description FROM em_content AS co LEFT JOIN em_contenttags AS ct ON co.content_id = ct.content_id LEFT JOIN em_tags AS ta ON ct.tag_id = ta.tag_id WHERE ta.tag IN (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $query);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
```

I've tried making `$query` an array and using placeholders for the "?" in the query and "s" in the `bind_param` variable, but I can't pass the `$query` as an array otherwise it throws an error.

Is there any way to make this work with prepared statements?

Just FYI, I'm not using PDO, I'm using mysqli

Comment: I know that, but I want to be able to select a random number of tags, so for example I search for "red apples", you might search for "green apples from new york". The length changes each time, but bind_param doesn't allow for arrays nor can I dynamically give it a random assortment of variables each time. That's the problem I'm having, so I can't send it as a string either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to build up the placeholders dynamically, so you'll have one `?` for each element of the array:

```
$array = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
$placeholders = join(',', array_fill(0, count($array), '?'));
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT ... WHERE IN (' . $placeholders . ')');
$stmt->execute($array);
```

Not 100% sure how to use MySQLi's `bind` mechanism here, the above works for PDO.

Comment: Yea I've seen something similar on stackoverflow somewhere, but it's all for PDO and not for mysqli. I don't want to have to change to PDO this far into the project either :( *sigh* might have to go down the mysqL_escape_string route

Comment: just add str_repeat() call to create something like "sss" string to use with mysqli bind

Comment: but then how do I add in the variables? In this case, the $query variable which contains an unknown number of tags. I can't do $stmt->execute($array); as mysqli doesn't allow for any variables to be passed in the execute function

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't use placeholders inside "IN()". You need to concatenate that part of the query.

Comment: I've got a workaround for getting placeholders for the IN part, but I can't seem to pass $query in "$stmt->bind_param("s", $query);" as an array which I thought was possible :( how do you concatenate that part of the query?

Comment: I meant something like this:
$sql = "SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE id IN (" . implode(",", $idList) . ")";
But you should check out the solution that was suggested by @deceze would be better if you can get it to work with mysqli_*

Comment: It would be a prepared statement but not that useful since you wouldn't be binding variables to it.